# Summing up a logical vector in R

Tags: r, logical-operators

```
patt<-c(`205` = FALSE, `210` = TRUE, `16` = TRUE, `2` = FALSE)    
totalobs<-0
{for (element in patt)
    if (element == TRUE){
    print (element)
    totalobs=totalobs+sum(element)
    }
print (totalobs)
}
```

I have a logical vector
[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plTUF.png), of which I want to add all the values of TRUE. With the above code I am only able to add up the amount of times TRUE is present in this vector, rather than the numbers that are above each TRUE value. I am quite new to R, how would I solve this?

Comment: `sum(patt)` maybe. Please share a minimal [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and show expected output.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and it also summed up to 10. Maybe some more information: the patt variable is generated from the mice package (md.pattern) which assigns a TRUE if a row has one NA value, and FALSE when it has no NA or more than one NA.

Comment: Please share sample data, use `dput` as shown in the link I posted earlier.

Comment: Thank you. I updated my original post.

Comment: Great! What is the result you are looking for?

Comment: I would like to add the TRUE values- basically add 210 and 16 in this case by an R command that adds all these values together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `patt` to subset `names(patt)`, convert the result to a numeric vector and finally use `sum` to get desired output as shown below

```
sum(as.numeric(names(patt)[patt]))
#[1] 226
```

---

If you need to do this kind of calculations more often then write a little function

```
Janne <- function(x) {
  sum(as.numeric(names(x)[x]))
}

Janne(patt)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this works perfectly! Appreciate your help!